# Ionic Lazy loading Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid link SecondPage

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am getting `Uncaught (in promise): invalid link SecondPage` error when I try to navigate to Second page lazily. Here is my code:

```
NavigateToSecondPage(): void{
    this.navCtrl.push('SecondPage');
}
```

Second page is in Ionic page generated using ionic-cli. Here is what the ts file looks like.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-second',
  templateUrl: 'second.html',
})
export class SecondPage { 

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

[image: Screenshot of the error]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should create the second-module.ts and update second.ts adding @IonicPage()

second-module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SecondPage } from './second';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
    SecondDetailPage,
   ],
   imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(SecondPage),
   ],
   exports: [
     SecondPage
  ]
})
export class SecondPageModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I too had too go through this and you have to keep two things in mind to use ionic lazy loading it needs the @IonicPage({}) decorator and the relative module.ts file. Its mentioned in [ionic lazy loading blog](https://blog.ionicframework.com/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/) the IonicPage decorator is how Ionic generates the proper mappings and URL slugs for your app at build time so its mandatory to add this decorator

So add the @IonicPage decorator in second.ts:

```
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage({})
@Component({
  selector: 'page-second',
  templateUrl: 'second.html',
})
export class SecondPage { 
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: 
  NavParams) {
  }
}
```

and add second-module.ts to the second page folder/component:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SecondPage } from './second';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SecondPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(SecondPage),
  ],
  exports: [
    SecondPage
  ]
})
export class SecondPageModule {}
```